# json_encode constantly returning null

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm trying to work with MySql and php to output json file. I've structured the query and json_encode and it's just working out. Tried reading forums and articles and tried various different things but nothing is bringing the result. I understand there's issue with the encoding, but despite trying so many things it still returns NULL.

Here's the code:

```
<?php require_once('Connections/db_con.php'); ?>
<?php
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT 
kkj_bsms_studies.studytext,
kkj_bsms_studies.id, 
kkj_bsms_studies.teacher_id, 
kkj_bsms_studies.studytitle, 
kkj_bsms_studies.studyintro,
kkj_bsms_studies.media_hours, 
kkj_bsms_studies.media_minutes, 
kkj_bsms_studies.media_seconds, 
kkj_bsms_teachers.teachername, 
kkj_bsms_mediafiles.server, 
kkj_bsms_mediafiles.`path`, 
kkj_bsms_mediafiles.filename, 
kkj_bsms_mediafiles.`size`, 
kkj_bsms_servers.server_path, 
kkj_bsms_folders.folderpath
FROM kkj_bsms_studies, kkj_bsms_teachers, kkj_bsms_mediafiles,
kkj_bsms_servers, kkj_bsms_folders
WHERE series_id = 8 AND kkj_bsms_teachers.id =kkj_bsms_studies.teacher_id AND  kkj_bsms_mediafiles.study_id = kkj_bsms_studies.id AND kkj_bsms_servers.id =     kkj_bsms_mediafiles.server AND kkj_bsms_folders.id = kkj_bsms_mediafiles.path");  

//Create an array
$json_response = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    $row_array['hour'] = $row['kkj_bsms_studies.media_hours'];

    //push the values in the array
    array_push($json_response,$row_array);
}
echo json_encode($json_response);

$error = json_last_error();
echo $error;
//Close the database connection
fclose($db);
?>
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Was the connection to the database ever opened? Or is it opened in the included file? It's possible it's returning null if nothing was returned from SQL.

Comment: 1) Why are you using array_push instead of just adding to the array, 2) Can you provide the output of `var_dump($json_response)` before the echo.

Comment: Please print $row here. not full record of the array. atleast two to three indexes valuse so that we can get a better idea.